# The use of an article for a psychological type of a person?

Tags: articles

If I want to draw a comparison between a person's behavior and a famous historical figure, how can it be done? For example, it's OK to say.

You are quite a Napoleon!

But what if I want to ask a person whether he/she thinks that he/she is like Napoleon. Can I say?

- Do you think you are a Napoleon?
- Do you think you are the Napoleon?
- Do you think you are Napoleon?

Apart from that, if I want to make it clear that the person is not Napoleon (in the sense, that the person doesn't belong to the psychological type of Napoleon), shall I say?

- You are not Napoleon!
- You are not the Napoleon!
- You are not a Napoleon!
- You are no Napoleon!

Comment: It's complicated. To me at least, both *He's quite a Napoleon!* and *He's quite **the** Napoleon!* are both perfectly okay. And although I'd prefer no article at all in *Do you think you're Hitler?*, I could at least "tolerate" *Do you think you're **a** Hitler?*, whereas *Do you think you're **the** Hitler?* just seems completely unacceptable.

Comment: @FF There _are / were_ quite a few people named Hitler.